# ¿Se puede agregar una propiedad personalizada a un archivo?

Tags: python

¿Es posible escribir desde Python una propiedad personalizada a un archivo?

Necesito agregar algunos atributos extras por ejemplo versión, descripción, etc.

Comment: ¿Con propiedades te refieres a las "externas"de cualquier archivo que dependen del sistema operativo y del sistema de archivos (NTFS, EXT4, XFS, ...)  por ejemplo fecha de creación, modificación, tamaño, etc ?¿O a metadatos específicos "internos" de un formato, como los de JPEG, AVI, etc (autor, álbum, género, etc)?

Comment: Sería escribir una propiedad con un nombre específico y que posteriormente pueda recuperar el valor de la misma.
Si esto es posible a través de una propiedad "externa" o "interna" me va a servir, pero quiero aplicarlos a varios tipos de archivos, es decir no a un tipo específico, si no a cualquier tipo. Muchas gracias por tu comentario!

Comment: Blasito en ese caso necesitas usar una propiedad que no se almacene dentro del contenido del propio fichero (es a lo que me refería con "interna") y por tanto no dependa del estándar de un formato determinado. El problema es que las propiedades externas dependen como digo del sistema operativo y son almacenadas usando el sistema de archivos (p.e mediante ADS en NTFS), lo que implica que se implementan y funcionan de distinta forma en un sistema que en otro, se pueden (y se suelen) perder al pasar archivos a otro sistema, en el copiado, etc.

Comment: Son propiedades que el sistema asocia al archivo, pero que no se almacenan dentro de él, lo cual las hace generalmente **una mala forma de almacenar información persistente y multiplataforma**, por eso muchos formatos  almacenan metadatos internamente en el mismo fichero, pero cada uno los implementa como le parece bien. . No se el uso real que le vas a dar, pero si esto lo va a usar solo tu programa hay formas alternativas de asociar información a los ficheros, por ejemplo implementando una pequeña base de datos sqlite.

Comment: Sea como sea teniendo lo anterior en cuenta sería necesario conocer el sistema operativo y el sistema de archivos objetivo para ver si hay forma de hacerlo, no es tanto un problema de Python por tanto, independientemente del lenguaje es un problema que hay que solventar lidiando con la API del sistema de archivos o el sistema operativo particular.

Comment: FJSevilla muchas gracias por tu comentario. El uso que le voy a dar es exclusivo de mi programa, por eso creo que me voy a inclinar en otras alternativas para asociar la información que deseo a los archivos ya que puede que me lleve más tiempo intentar agregar las propiedades directamente a los archivos "internas" o asociarlos de manera "externa" a través del sistema de archivos  y como mencionaste que puede que no sea una buena forma de hacerlo ya que dependen del sistema operativo.